# Symfony2 sublevel query

Tags: mysql, symfony, repository

I'm trying to get a list of flights from a search form. User picks a city, a number of passengers, and my query returns all available flights.

I tried this one :

```
public function findSearch($city, $nbpax)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

    $qb->where('a.precisedate >= :now')
        ->setParameter('now', new \DateTime())
        ->andWhere('a.available > :min')
        ->setParameter('min', $nbpax)
        ->andWhere('a.departure > :min')
        ->setParameter('min', $nbpax)
        ->andWhere('a.departure.city = :city')
        ->setParameter('city', $city)
        ->orderBy('a.precisedate', 'ASC')
    ;

    return $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

But it seems like the a.departure.city is not recognised as a valid comparison (departure is an airport, linked to a city with a OneToMany relationship)

How can I change my query so that I can access the airport city ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do a join on departure prior to the comparisons, so:

```
$qb->join('a.departure', 'd')
```

And then instead of `a.departure` you'd just do `d`, e.g.

```
->andWhere('d.city = :city')
```

The part I don't understand is the `a.departure > :min` clause, what field on a departure entity are you comparing against? Or is departure a field? In which case the `a.departure.city = :city` doesn't make sense.

Regardless, the [DQL documentation on joins](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) is a good source of reference.

Comment: This is brilliant. Both the answer and the documentation.